# Create new entity with current entity using MagicalRecord

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I am trying to create a new entity using an existing entity (passed in) set set all the values .  Here is the class method that I am using in the Managed Object Subclass:

```
+(FlightManifest *)getNextFlightManifestLegWithFlightManifest:(FlightManifest *)fm {
    // Get the current context
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];

    // Set a var to the cur leg so we can use it to increment the leg number later
    NSInteger curLeg = [fm.leg intValue];

    // Check to see if we already have the next leg saved
    if ([self getFlightManifestWithTripID:fm.tripid andLeg:[NSNumber numberWithInt:curLeg + 1]] !=nil) {
        return [self getFlightManifestWithTripID:fm.tripid andLeg:[NSNumber numberWithInt:curLeg + 1]];
    } else {
        // Create a new leg using the passed in FlightManifest for the values
        FlightManifest *newFM = [FlightManifest MR_createInContext:moc];  

        // Set the value of the newly created object to the one passed in
        newFM = fm;

        // Increment the leg number
        newFM.leg = [NSNumber numberWithInt:curLeg + 1];

        // Save the object
        [moc MR_save];

        return newFM;
    }
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
- (IBAction)nextLegButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    currentFlight = [FlightManifest getNextFlightManifestLegWithFlightManifest:currentFlight];
    self.legNumberLabel.text = [currentFlight.leg stringValue];
    [self reloadLegsTableViewData];
}
```

What is happening is that I am changing the current entity instead of creating a new one.  Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You need to share the code for MR_createInContext

Comment: That is part of the MagicalRecord API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may seem obvious, but this line seems suspicious:

```
// Set the value of the newly created object to the one passed in
    newFM = fm;
```

This would make the code after use the existing fm object...and change the one your trying to copy...

Comment: Yes, I am trying to copy all the properties from the one passed in and then change one of those properties (the leg).  Since ManagedObjects don't have a copy method, I am unsure what else to do except set each property like this: newFM.tripid = fm.tripid; ...  That works BTW, but it sure doesn't seem the most efficient way.

Comment: That is exactly what you'd need to do :( If you perform a deep copy from one managed object to another, you're effectively going to copy the entire object graph. In this case, manually copying properties seems like the best way to go.

Comment: Ok, if you put that last comment in your answer, I will accept it.  Thanks.